# Pandas Format Style in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to know how can I store the new format into a new data frame initially i load my csvfile.

`python`

```
df = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv",encoding='ISO-8859-1')
df.head(5)

data = datadf.head(5).style.format({'CSS %': '{:.2%}',
'A %':  '{:.2%}',
'B %':  '{:.2%}',
'C %':  '{:.2%}',
'D':    '{:.4}'})
```

whenever to run **df.head** or **df.describe** it goes back to the old format
**just like i never** run any **style format** at all

Comment: When you print `data` what is it?

Comment: it turns to the old format as if there is no style format was run